# Popup existing Jframe when clicking button in another Jframe

Tags: java, swing, popup, jframe, jbutton

i am working in JAVA GUI project with netbeans ,,
I just created Jframe and put a button on it ,,
I created also another JFrame and added many labels 
I am asking how can the second JFrame appears when i click on the button in the first JFrame

Comment: You may also wish to consider [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        new SecondFrame().setVisible(true);
        FirstFrame.this.dispose(); // if you want the first frame to close
    }
```

Check out [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more information.

Comment: In addtion, if you just want to hide the first frame, use `firstFrame.setVisible(false)`.

Comment: well ,, but when i closed the new popup window ,, the all app closed .. how can i keep the first frame working ???

Comment: In the second frame add a `WindowAdapter` and override `windowClosing` to reopen the first frame. Look [here (the Oracle docs)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) for details.